# Unknown option to s when trying to replace line with #

Tags: bash, shell, sed

In a bash script, I'm trying to replace a line which starts with a comment with new text. The sed fails telling me that the hash char is an `Unknown option to s`

`sed -i -e "s/#a line/the new line with some $varname/g" "path/to/filename"`

I've tried one backslash on the # to no avail. How do I use a hash with sed, and yes, I have to use double quotes to manage the variable use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `#`. You get the error because the variable you are injecting into the sed script happen to contain `/` characters. If you know a character that will definitely not appear in the pattern or replacement, use that as separator for the `s` command instead. E.g. assuming `|` is safe:

```
sed "s|#a line|the new line with some $varname|" file > file.tmp &&
mv file.tmp file
```

Alternatively, the `c` command can be used to change the whole line:

```
sed "/#a line/c\\
the new line with some $varname" file > file.tmp &&
mv file.tmp file
```

Or better, find a way to do it without injecting data into code (E.g. ed, ex or awk)

Comment: This did it! For future reference if you add a line of code showing a new separator I'll accept!